# Calculating minimum straight line distance in R

Tags: distance, shortest-path, rstudio

I am trying to calculate a minimum straight-line distance from the district headquarters to the nearest national highway network. I have the district headquarters latitude and longitude in a different data set, and the national highway network shapefile for this.

I am completely new to GIS.

How can I do this in Rstudio?

Here head_X and head_Y are the longitude and latitude respectively of the district quarters.

```
structure(list(`_id` = structure(c(125, 126, 127, 128, 129), label = "_ID", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    `_cx` = structure(c(76.3474502563477, 76.315071105957, 77.6141815185547, 
    77.3953247070312, 76.9909515380859), label = "_CX", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    `_cy` = structure(c(32.6752319335938, 32.1089706420898, 32.4812507629395, 
    31.9050388336182, 31.6380405426025), label = "_CY", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    pc11_s_id = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    pc11_d_id = structure(c(23, 24, 25, 26, 27), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    d_name = structure(c("Chamba", "Kangra", "Lahul & Spiti", 
    "Kullu", "Mandi"), format.stata = "%27s"), head_x = structure(c(76.1258087158203, 
    76.3234024047852, 77.0319747924805, 77.1094589233398, 76.9313659667969
    ), label = "head_X", format.stata = "%8.0g"), head_y = structure(c(32.5533638000488, 
    32.2190437316895, 32.5709991455078, 31.9578514099121, 31.7081661224365
    ), label = "head_Y", format.stata = "%8.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have posted the highway shapefile on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xIFuwWB2I2FNCOUHKzMotYx3phLsot30/view?usp=sharing

I have uploaded the shapefile on R using read_sf but I have no clue what to do next.

Comment: Take a look at `st_distance` in the sf package.